# dpkg package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2 on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, docker

I used Docker to set up an Ubuntu 18.04 container, and then tried to install the .deb file with an error as shown below.

```
root@hashirama:/sc5xx_dev/lib/toolchain# dpkg -i  adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb 
(Reading database ... 52942 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb (--install):
 new adi-cces-2.7.0:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb
```

Output of `sudo apt install ./adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb`:

> dpkg: error processing archive /sc5xx_dev/lib/toolchain/adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb (--unpack): 
>      new adi-cces-2.7.0:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2 
>      Errors were encountered while processing: /sc5xx_dev/lib/toolchain/adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please try `sudo apt install ./adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb`.

Comment: Thanks for your warm heart, I try that but still has error:

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /sc5xx_dev/lib/toolchain/adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb (--unpack):
 new adi-cces-2.7.0:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /sc5xx_dev/lib/toolchain/adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.7.0.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Could you please share a link, where I can download yours ADI tool?

Comment: Apologize for checking the mesage late, link is here http://download.analog.com/tools/CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio/Releases/Release_2.8.0/adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it seems that it was broken download issue.
I have downloaded your file:

```
wget http://download.analog.com/tools/CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio/Releases/Release_2.8.0/adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb
```

and checked it size

> $ ls -al adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb
>      -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 580754562 ноя 25 12:33 adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb

also I checked MD5 sum:

> $ md5sum adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb
>   2814b42b1fdefa254701b2c802e35c1d  adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb

It installs normally:

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install ./adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb 
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Note, selecting 'adi-cces-2.8.0:i386' instead of './adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb'
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   adi-cces-2.8.0:i386
> 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 0 B/581 MB of archives.
> After this operation, 1 644 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> Get:1 /home/user/adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb adi-cces-2.8.0 i386 2.8.0 [581 MB]
> Selecting previously unselected package adi-cces-2.8.0:i386.
> (Reading database ... 215776 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb ...
> Unpacking adi-cces-2.8.0:i386 (2.8.0) ...
> Setting up adi-cces-2.8.0:i386 (2.8.0) ...
> Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
> Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
> Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
> Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
> ```

Also you need to install 32-bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libxtst6:i386
```

Consider to redownload the file.

Comment: Hi dear, Really thanks for your guiding for that, I can install it successfully following your comment in the OS ubuntu-18.04(do use the docker image), bu still have the issue in docker image using. Thanks again.

Comment: I got what's wrong with my configuration, I set the Dockerfile "ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive" to auto-build the image, but for my package adi-CrossCoreEmbeddedStudio-linux-x86-2.8.0.deb, it need not in the  noninteractive mode, so the error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

I find how to solve this question. It's caused by the "`ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`"  in `Dockerfile`.

To install the ubuntu-18.04 we should set the package in the mode of noninteractive
To install the `adi_xxx.deb` package we should set the event in the mode of interactive.

So The correct Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -q install net-tools build-essential minicom tftpd-hpa git-all subversion openssh-server ncurses-dev php gawk g++ m4 libncurses5-dev texinfo flex bison php-cli vim php-xml python-setuptools python-dev unzip rsync cpio bc lib32z1 lib32stdc++6 lib32ncurses5
```

The wrong Dockerfile:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y -q install net-tools build-essential minicom tftpd-hpa git-all subversion openssh-server ncurses-dev php gawk g++ m4 libncurses5-dev texinfo flex bison php-cli vim php-xml python-setuptools python-dev unzip rsync cpio bc lib32z1 lib32stdc++6 lib32ncurses5
```

Note:
Do not use the command "`ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`" in configuring the `Dockerfile` this is definitely not a reasonable default, and setting it via `ENV` should be actively discouraged, Refer to https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4032